# Why redisRepository.findById doesn't work

Tags: spring, redis, jwt, refresh-token

I'm trying to manage refresh token w redis. I checked that the data exists on redis when I saved new Redis `redisRepository.save(new Redis(userEmail, token.getRefreshToken()));`.

But when I used redisRepository.findByEmail, it returned null even if the exact data exists on redis. I don't understand why it doesn't returns the data.

Redis

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisHash;

@RedisHash(value = "refreshToken", timeToLive = 60 * 60 * 24 * 14)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Redis {
    @Id
    private String email;
    private String refreshToken;
}
```

RedisRepository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface RedisRepository extends CrudRepository<Redis, String> {
    Optional<Redis> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Comment: Are there any logs? Have you tried findById?